# issue with jQuery ajax url for all pages in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the below code to show number of new messages in every link across the application on page load in a `js` file inside public folder of laravel.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: "profile/newmessages",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    beforeSend: function(){
      $("#new_messages_number").empty().append('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
    },
    success:function(response){
      $("#new_messages_number").empty().append(response.length);
    }
  });
```

It works for links with single slash, for example `localhost:8000/foo` or `localhost:8000/bar`. However for links with multiple slashes for example `localhost:8000/foo/bar` I get below error

```
GET http://localhost:8000/foo/profile/newmessages 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Edit: Here is the route for this url

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'profile', 'namespace' => 'Profile'], function () {

    Route::get('/newmessages', 'MessageController@newMessages');

});
```

Comment: add your routes

Comment: Check if you can connect directly to `http://localhost:8000/foo/profile/newmessages`

Comment: Or prolly a `findOrFail` messages thrown from controller.

Comment: I have added the route, please check

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first, to give an alias to your route

```
Route::get('/newmessages', 'MessageController@newMessages')->name('new.messages');
```

And then in your ajax request:

```
var url = "{{ route('new.messages') }}";

  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
    },
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    beforeSend: function(){
      $("#new_messages_number").empty().append('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
    },
    success:function(response){
      $("#new_messages_number").empty().append(response.length);
    }
  });
```

If this doesn't work, check if your route actually exists by running the `php artisan route:list` command

Comment: Jquery doesn't understand the route

Comment: @Hasan what do you mean with “jQuery doesn’t understand the route“?

Comment: I mean typing route like that in the js file doesn't work. Maybe it would work if the js code was inside php file

Comment: Well if the JavaScript part is in another file and not in blade file, you could open a variable inside a script in your blade file, and then require the JS file that uses that route and it should work perfectly.